# Multiple data sets in p5.js bar chart

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm trying to a simple graphic using this base I found:

```js
let data = []

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 400)
  // array data filled with objects
  // Objects are variables too. But objects can contain many values.
  // The values are written as name:value pairs 
  // (name and value separated by a colon)
  data = [{
      size: 99,
      label: "Piano Pratice"
    },
    {
      size: 98,
      label: "MRT Cabin"
    },
    {
      size: 97,
      label: "Wedding Event"
    },
    {
      size: 92,
      label: "Road Junction"
    },
    {
      size: 90,
      label: "Kopitiam"
    },
    {
      size: 88,
      label: "Swimming Pool"
    },
    {
      size: 86,
      label: "Ion Orchard"
    },
    {
      size: 85,
      label: "Rain"
    },
    {
      size: 83,
      label: "Hair Salon"
    },
    {
      size: 80,
      label: "Supermarket"
    },
    {
      size: 75,
      label: "Chinese Restaurant"
    },
    {
      size: 75,
      label: "Gym"
    },
    {
      size: 74,
      label: "Bedok Reservoir Park"
    },
    {
      size: 73,
      label: "National Design Centre"
    },
    {
      size: 71,
      label: "InterContinental Hotel Lobby"
    },
    {
      size: 70,
      label: "Changi Airport Terminal 2"
    },
    {
      size: 56,
      label: "National Library"
    },
    {
      size: 56,
      label: "Office"
    },
    {
      size: 53,
      label: "Lasalle Lecture Theatre"
    },
    {
      size: 23,
      label: "Empty Room"
    }
  ]

  colors = [color(55, 255, 0),
    color(204, 255, 0),
    color(238, 255, 0),
    color(255, 212, 0),
    color(255, 182, 0),
    color(255, 157, 0),
    color(255, 123, 0),
    color(255, 97, 0),
    color(255, 63, 0),
    color(255, 16, 0)
  ]

  noStroke()
}

function draw() {
  background(28, 110, 127)
  textSize(20)
  fill(255)
  textStyle(BOLD)
  text('Average Noise Level (dB)', 185, 40)
  textSize(12)
  push()
  translate(55, 210)
  // 
  data.forEach((el, i) => {
    push()
    translate(i * 25, 0)
    let c = floor(map(el.size, 23, 99, 0, 9))
    fill(colors[c])
    rect(0, 0, 20, -el.size * 1.5)
    fill(28, 110, 127)
    push()
    translate(0, 10)
    text(el.size, 3.5, -18)
    rotate(HALF_PI)
    fill(255)
    textStyle(ITALIC)
    text(el.label, 0, -6)
    pop()
    pop()
  });
  
  pop()
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

I've already put my first series of numbers, however i now need to create a second graph on the same file, using WAY larger numbers. I saw the way numbers are displayed is dictated by `data` and `data.forEach()`. Is there a way to have multiples `data` and `data.forEach()` statements? So i can have more than one value.

Comment: You need to be more specific about the second series. Does it contain all of the same labels?

Comment: Yes, the same labels but different sizes

Answer (score 0):

The code you are starting with is not very dynamic. Here's what you need to do:

1. Calculate the minimum and maximum values for each series of values, rather than hard coding that.
2. Make each bar narrower to make space for the second series of values.
3. Separate the drawing of the bar height values from the label.
4. Replicate the bar drawing code to draw the second bar.
5. Optional make the horizontal spacing calculated based on the number of data points.

```js
let data = []

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 400)
  // array data filled with objects
  // Objects are variables too. But objects can contain many values.
  // The values are written as name:value pairs 
  // (name and value separated by a colon)
  data = [{
      value1: 94,
      value2: 7826,
      label: "Foo"
    },
    {
      value1: 67,
      value2: 2193,
      label: "Bar"
    },
    {
      value1: 43,
      value2: 8265,
      label: "Baz"
    }
  ]

  colors = [color(55, 255, 0),
    color(204, 255, 0),
    color(238, 255, 0),
    color(255, 212, 0),
    color(255, 182, 0),
    color(255, 157, 0),
    color(255, 123, 0),
    color(255, 97, 0),
    color(255, 63, 0),
    color(255, 16, 0)
  ]

  noStroke()

  noLoop();
}

function draw() {
  background(28, 110, 127)
  textSize(20)
  fill(255)
  textStyle(BOLD)
  text('Value 1 / Value 2', 185, 40);
  textSize(12)

  push()
  translate(55, 210)
  // Calculate the minimum and maximum values for each series being plotted
  let [min1, max1, min2, max2] = data.reduce(
    ([mn1, mx1, mn2, mx2], d) => [
      Math.min(mn1, d.value1),
      Math.max(mx1, d.value1),
      Math.min(mn2, d.value2),
      Math.max(mx2, d.value2)
    ], [Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY, 0, Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY, 0]
  );

  // Calculate the width of the bars dynamically
  let w = (width - 110) / data.length - 5;
  data.forEach((el, i) => {
    push()
    translate(i * (w + 5), 0);
    // Draw bar #1
    // Use our calculated min and max instead of using hard coded values
    let c = round(map(el.value1, min1, max1, 0, colors.length - 1))
    fill(colors[c])
    // make half width rectangles, using negative height so that they appear above the origin
    rect(0, 0, w / 2, map(el.value1, 0, max1, 0, -150))
    // Draw the values as part of each bar
    fill(28, 110, 127)
    text(`${el.value1}`, 4, -4)

    push()
    translate(w / 2, 0)

    // Draw bar #2
    c = round(map(el.value2, min2, max2, 0, colors.length - 1))
    fill(colors[c])
    rect(0, 0, w / 2, map(el.value2, 0, max2, 0, -150))
    fill(28, 110, 127)
    text(`${el.value2}`, 4, -4)
    pop()

    // Draw the label
    translate(w / 2 - 9, 10)
    rotate(HALF_PI)
    fill(255)
    textStyle(ITALIC)
    text(el.label, 0, -6)

    pop()
  });

  pop()
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```